# how does process.env.ROOT_URL work

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, heroku

I'm following [this sample](https://github.com/node-facebook/facebook-node-sdk/blob/master/samples/scrumptious/config.js) and they use `config.rootUrl  = process.env.ROOT_URL                  || 'http://localhost:3000/';` I thought this would mean it would get the url of the page depending on the environment. When I use my app on heroku to go to fb. it reports an error `Can't Load URL` . I see when I hover the link somewhere it shows the localhost link and not the website name. So how does process.env.ROOT_URL work ?

or where do they define `process.env.ROOT_URL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROOT_URL` is just an environment variable. On Heroku, you can set it like:

```
$ heroku config:set ROOT_URL='whateveryouwant'
```

Answer (score 1):

ROOT_URL should be an environment variable, so when you run your app, it should look something like this:

```
user$ ROOT_URL="http://something.com/" node app.js
```

If ROOT_URL is not declared, it will default to localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

in your terminal / command line

```
export ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000/
```

then you can run your node script

```
node index.js
```

---

as mentioned by the previous answers `process.env` references all system variables available in the current terminal / command line session

so for instance, you could see the value of your `HOME` folder by doing the following

```
console.log(process.env.HOME)
```